# where are ssh.com's crypticore and seed defined?

Tags: encryption, ssh

[ssh.com's Tectia](https://www.ssh.com/products/tectia-ssh/index.html) offers a few algorithms seemingly unique to itself. Chief among them: crypticore128@ssh.com, crypticore-mac@ssh.com and seed-cbc@ssh.com

Are these algorithms publicly defined anywhere or are the proprietary algorithms?

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Maeher - weird. Doesn't work for me either. But that is, none-the-less, the link I get if I go to Products -> Tectia SSH Client/Server on ssh.com. Maybe it's doing some funky redirects if you visit that URL without having ssh.com as the referer. That'd be retarded but it's pretty retarded that you can't visit that link directly either...

Comment: [SEED was a Korean standard also available as an RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEED), although AIUI officially it has been superseded by ARIA. AFAICT crypticore is proprietary.

Comment: @Maeher Fixed link by guessing `index.html`. Note that it may be because of cookie settings / browser's blocking thingies.

Comment: I don't see any mention of an algorithm of that name, but I do see an HCC HSM with the same name (using bog-standard algorithms), which of course supports SSH. So maybe they mean that. ssh.com seems to be governed by a bunch of management style overlords (for uh, lack of a better word), but I think you're still better off asking **them**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### seed-cbc@ssh.com

[SEED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEED) is a block cipher specified in [RFC 4269](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4269) and is standardized in  [ISO/IEC 18033-3:2010](https://www.iso.org/standard/54531.html) (which also specifies Camellia and AES). It is not unique to any Tectia product. It was designed by [KISA](https://www.kisa.or.kr/EN) (Korea Internet & Security Agency). While SEED is not particularly popular outside of Korea, it is or has been at one time supported by a number of cryptographic suits and protocols. As the name implies, seed-cbc@ssh.com uses SEED in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)).

### crypticore128@ssh.com

This is likely the [Rabbit stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_(cipher)). Tectia's website [lists supported algorithms](https://docs.ssh.com/manuals/clientserver-product/53/cs-standards.html), and it includes:

> - CryptiCore (Rabbit) (128-bit key)

Additionally, [the Rabbit paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/291.pdf) was published by Cryptoco, whose technology [was purchased by Tectia](https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2004/09/28/ssh-adopts-data-protection-technology-from-cryptico/). It contains the following trademark message in the reference implementation for Rabbit:

```
/* Cryptico, CryptiCore, the Cryptico logo and "Re-thinking encryption" are */
/* either trademarks or registered trademarks of Cryptico A/S.              */
```

Finally, CryptiCore is advertised as being extremely fast on x86 processors, and the Rabbit stream cipher is famously extremely light weight and performant. CryptiCore uses a 128-bit key, and Rabbit uses a 128-bit key. For these reasons, I'm confident that crypticore128@ssh.com uses Rabbit.

### crypticore-mac@ssh.com

This is probably the [MMH-Badger MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMH-Badger_MAC), described [in this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/319.pdf) by the same authors of Rabbit. Tectia's webpage also contains the following in their list of data integrity algorithms:

> - CryptiCore (Badger) (16-byte key)

While the Tectia implementations of Rabbit and Badger may be proprietary, the underlying algorithms are not. Rabbit has some distinguishers in the keystream, but they are too weak to have any practical impact on its security. This does not mean that I would recommend anyone use Rabbit for security due to it getting relatively little attention from cryptographers. As for the Badger MAC, it is provably secure (which for MACs isn't uncommon. Poly1305 and GCM, for example, are also provably secure if the cipher they are used with is).